# Python vs. R: apply a function to each element in a vector

Tags: python, apply

I want to apply a function (`len`) over each element in a vector. In R I can easily do this with `sapply(cities,char)`. Is there an alternative like this in Python WITHOUT writing a loop?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: What about a list comprehension? `[len(el) for el in vector]`. It's more Pythonic than `map`.

Comment: But `sapply` is a loop!

Answer (score 15):

The syntax is `map(function, list)`.

Example:

```
map(len, [ [ 1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])
```

Output:

```
[ 3, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 6):

The R `sapply()` could be replaced with a list comprehension, but fair enough a list comprehension doesn't strictly avoid the *writing* of a **loop**.

In addition to `map()` you should take a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/comparison_with_r.html), which provides Python alternatives to several of the functionality that people use in R.

```
import pandas as pd

vector = [1,2,3,4,5]
square_vector = pd.Series(vector).apply(lambda x: x**2)  
print square_vector.tolist()
```

The above code results in a new list with the square values of the imput:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Here, I passed the vector to a series constructor `pd.Series(vector)` and apply an anonymus function `apply(lambda x: x**2)`. The output is a pandas series which can be converted back to a list if desired `tolist()`. Pandas series have a lot of functionalities and are ideal for many data manipulation and analysis tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function map that receives a function to apply to an iterable. Documentation to map map: [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

For example, you cans pass an anonymus function (using lambda) to apply to each element to the list by this way:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[1]*2 + 3, [[1,2,3], [1,4]])
[7, 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
cities = ['new york', 'tokyo', 'paris']
sapply_equivalent = [len(city) for city in cities]
```

Then `sapply_equivalent` returns `[8, 5, 5]`

Comment: This is called a list comprehension. I like this answer.